# JSP Expression Language on Jackson's JsonNode

Tags: jsp, el, jackson

Let's say I'm using Spring and have a controller that returns a model containing a field `data` that is an instance of [Jackson's `ObjectNode`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.6.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/node/ObjectNode.html). Within `data` I have a `StringBuilder` named `log`.

In the JSP I use

```
${data}
```

and I get this output:

```
{"log":hello world}
```

Now if I want to access `log` I thought I could use

```
${data["log"]}
```

but all I get is

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'log' not found on type org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:214)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:191)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:300)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:81)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:938)
    :
```

`${data.log}` shows the same.

I know that according to the EL `data.log` looks for a method `getLog()` on `data`, but IIRC `Maps<?,?>` support this kind of access to its keys. Is there any similar way to make it work with Jackson? Or if that just doesn't work this way, how would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I revisited this issue, I wrote my own [ELResolver](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaif) for [ArrayNode](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/node/ArrayNode.html) and [ObjectNode](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/node/ObjectNode.html). Helpful links were

- http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/reference/techart/unifiedEL.html#Features_of_the_Unified_EL (look for "Writing an ELResolver Implementation")
- http://pukkaone.github.com/2011/01/03/jsp-cross-site-scripting-elresolver.html

EDIT:
As far as the ArrayNode is concerned, it helped me to look at [Tomcat's ArrayELResolver](http://massapi.com/source/apache-tomcat-6.0.29-src/java/javax/el/ArrayELResolver.java.html). It's pretty easy to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with EL in a while, so I'm guessing a bit...

Since `ObjectNode` does not implement `Map` and does not define a property getter for "log", perhaps a different approach is necessary.  (I'm guessing the example EL only works on `Map` instances and beans.)

Instead of putting Jackson implementations in your view (the JSP), does it make sense to populate an appropriate Java structure (without any Jackson classes in it) from the data in the Jackson structure, and then just pass the view the Jackson-free Java structure?  Then, binding Java data to view elements would be more straightforward.

Since one of Jackson's strengths is generally making it very easy to populate Java structures from JSON data, I'd think this approach would be relatively easy.

Comment: I see your point, but there have been plenty of discussions and it was decided that we will use Jackson-classes in that scenario. One key aspect to this was how we retrieve the data from an external data source. So that's something I can't work around. Between the lines you pretty much agree to what I had lined out so I guess I will have to code some sort of wrapper for this.